# TypeError: Cannot read property 'set' of undefined

Tags: bots, discord, discord.js

I'm creating a discord bot using the **discord.js v12.2.0** library. In my file **Command.js**, I have this code:

```
const { readdirSync } = require("fs")

module.exports = (Bot) => {
    const load = dirs => {
        const Commands = readdirSync(`./SRC/Commands/${dirs}/`).filter(d => d.endsWith('.js'));
        for (let file of Commands) {
            let pull = require(`../Commands/${dirs}/${file}`);
            Bot.Commands.set(pull.config.name, pull);
            if (pull.config.aliases) pull.config.aliases.forEach(a => Bot.aliases.set(a, pull.config.name));
          };
        };
        ["Miscellaneous", "Moderation", "Owner"].forEach(x => load(x));
};
```

This is my **Index.js** file:

```
const { Client, Collection } = require("discord.js");
const { Token } = require("./Config.json");
const Bot = new Client();

["aliases", "commands"].forEach(x => Bot[x] = new Collection());
["console", "command", "event"].forEach(x => require(`./SRC/Handlers/${x}`)(Bot));

Bot.login(Token);
```

The error I get from running this code is **TypeError: Cannot read property 'set' of undefined**

This is my [Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJQAL.png)

Comment: Can you add the call to the exported function in your question ? As it is, we do not know what `Bot` is

Comment: There is no `aliases` property in any object or class of discord.js, so `Bot.aliases` is undefined, which causes your error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you initialized `Bot.Commands` to a `Discord.Collection()` ?

index.js or whatever main file

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const Bot = new Discord.Client();
Bot.Commands = new Discord.Collection();

//or
const { Client, Collection } = require("discord.js");
const Bot = new Client();
Bot.Commands = new Collection();
```

I would suggest you make Bot and commands lowercase as that's the convention in js, and helps others understand better.